# Correct way to send a POST request with Python (urllib2 , base64 and json)

Tags: python, json, post, base64, urllib2

I need to send thousands of POST requests.
I searched information on the web and after many tries I coded
the following solution:

```
post_data = urllib.urlencode({'pushes': b64encode(json.dumps(pushes))})
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent,
            'Content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'Accept': "text/plain"}
request = urllib2.Request(PUSH_URL, data=post_data, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

pushes is a list of dictionaries.

Most of times this solution works fine, but sometimes it causes a segmentation fault on destination server (Apache). I have monitored the opened connections on destination server.
The number of connections is low (100-200).
Perhaps my code is not 100% correct.
I need a more reliable solution.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE - Jan 25 2013**
I used strace to debug the apache web server (destination server).
I found out that there is some problem with the syscall 'gettimeofday' which is used by the Zend Framework.
I tried to moved the zend application in two different servers,
Centos and Ubuntu Server 12.04.
The PHP version was changed from 5.3 to 5.4 too.
I always got the same problem with strace.

I ported the application to another framework. The problem is vanished.
The code on the source server which does the POST requests was not modified.

Comment: Have you seen [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the segfaults on Apache, why do you think the issue is with your code? What I'd do is to take a close look on what's happening with Apache, when its dying - turn on debug logging, strace/ktrace its process, and finally test if the same happens when using other http server, like Nginx or Lighttpd.
Without knowing why Apache is dying, you cant try to even remediate that on your side, in the code (even if the right solution is to fix the Apache).

Comment: On Apache I get this error:
[Mon Jan 21 10:19:21 2013] [notice] child pid 19692 exit signal Segmentation fault (11).
I've tried Lighttpd already. Using Lighttpd I get an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: Well, that's a great start to debugging :) Go ahead and hunt that issue - enable more verbose logging, not only in Apache, but also in whatever is handling that traffic (some PHP app? Perl CGI? whatever), strace/ktrace the process and find out what's really happening.

Comment: On the destination server it's deployed a Zend app.
My boss suggested to use strace too, but sincerely I wanted to avoid it (I've never used it and I'm lazy). Eventually I will document myself.

Comment: I'm joking. My boss want me to use strace. ASAP I will write a feedback.